# How to get user values in login php?

Tags: php, validation, pdo, authentication

i want validate username and password with php and mysql.

Im used rowCount for know if user exist or not, but also if exist (rowCount > 0) i want get values from user.

```
public static function validateUser($user)
{
    $dto = NULL;
    $exist = false;

    $strUsername = $user->getUsername();
    $strPassword = $user->getPassword();

    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDOClass();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("select username, password, name, age, ocupation, id from user where username = ? AND password = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $strUsername);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $strPassword);
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
       if($stmt->rowCount()>0) {
           exist true;
           //get user values
           $user->setName(??);
           $user->setAge(??);
       }

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo"Error SQL ".$ex->getMessage();
    }

    return $exist;
}
```

Comment: What is `PDOClass`? Are you using some type of framework?

Comment: Hi, it's the class of connection to mysql, im not using framework,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
if($stmt->rowCount()>0) {
    exist true;
    //get user values
    $user->setName(??);
    $user->setAge(??);
}
```

You would do:

```
// Fetch only one row
$resultado = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($resultado !== false) {
    // If the user exists you can get its name and age and perform any  
    // kind of validation you want
    $user->setName($resultado['name']);
    $user->setAge($resultado['age']);
}
```

Comment: No problem. If you are happy with it please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get values from user you have to use HTML form with Text field and Password field. Once the user press submit button retrieve the values from those fields using PHP $_REQUEST[ ] or $_GET[ ] or $_POST[ ] global variables.

```
 <form method="" action="">
 Username
<input type="text" name="user">
PasSword
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Php code

```
$user=$_REQUEST["user"];
$pass=$_REQUEST["pass"]
```